# I made apps for twitter,when i post the tweets,error is coming

Tags: android

error----Exception processing async thread queue Exception processing async thread queue java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

```
package com.android.otweet.tasks;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class PostTweetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, twitter4j.Status> {

    private Twitter twitter;
    private PostTweetResponder responder;

    public PostTweetAsyncTask(PostTweetResponder responder, Twitter twitter) {
        super();
        this.twitter = twitter;
        this.responder = responder;
    }

    public interface PostTweetResponder {
        public void tweetPosting();
        public void tweetPosted(twitter4j.Status tweet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(twitter4j.Status result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        responder.tweetPosted(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        responder.tweetPosting();
    }

    @Override
    protected twitter4j.Status doInBackground(String... params) {
        String tweet = params[0];
        try {
            return twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't post status", e);
        }
    }
}
```

error is coming in doBackground().

Comment: You will need to give more context to your question. Just dumping the code on the site and expecting people to debug it for you is not the way Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Post your manifest file, did you enable the internet permission?

Answer (score 0):

This code will be beneficial for you

```
class UpdateTweetTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_wait_string));
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String status = params[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.TwitterConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.TwitterConstants.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token
                String access_token = IVvyApplication.getSharedPreference(Constants.SharedPreferenceName.TWITTER_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SharedPreferenceKey.PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret =IVvyApplication.getSharedPreference(Constants.SharedPreferenceName.TWITTER_PREFERENCE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SharedPreferenceKey.PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);




            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                AppLog.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hideProgressDialog();
        startTimer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not returning any value in doInBackGroung method. As you have made the doInBackGroung method of Twitter4j type then ypu should return a value which is of Twitter4j type in the method. Else your code will return nothing and will show errors because your output will be coming from Twiiter4j.Status.You have to return the value in catch statement too of your doInBackgroung method.

Comment: The doInBackground() method does return something in the try, and throws a RuntimeException in the catch.  The method is done properly.

Comment: Thanks I solved my problam...my code was correct.actully i was registered my apps readonly,thats why i was nt able to post the tweets..but thaks a lot